# Morphism of integral $k$-schemes of finite type and closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm trying to understand the proof that the categories of prevarieties is equivalent to the category of integral $k$-schemes of finite type, as done in Görtz-Wedhorn's book. In this proof, one considers the functor that associates to a integral $k$-scheme of finite type the space $X(k)$ of closed points in $X$. If $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of integral $k$-schemes of finite type, then one can define $f(k)$ - the image of $f$ under the above defined functor - as simply the restriction of $f$ to $X(k)$ (as a continuous map, I mean). I'm trying to show that this definition makes sense, i.e., that $f(X(k)) \subseteq Y(k)$, but I'm kind of stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This should be pretty direct from the definition of a $k$-point - what definition do you have?

Comment: The book gives three equivalent definitions:


1 - $x$ is a closed point;


2 - $k(x) = k$;


3 - An element of $Hom_k(Spec k, X)$.

Comment: Hint: If you have a $k$-map $\operatorname{Spec} k\to X$ and a $k$-map $X\to Y$, what do these combine to give you?

Comment: I see your point, it is kind of clear now. I just need to tie up the equivalent definitions now. Thank you